# How do I write a more concise 2 stage promise in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

The use case I have here:

- If a resource is available immediately then return it
- If a resource is not available yet, then show a modal or loading indicator, then wait for it to be ready
- The modal logic must be decoupled from the promise/request logic

Is there a better design pattern for this?

```
let twoStagePromise = (state: boolean): Promise<{ ready: boolean, wait: Promise<any>; }> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (state) {
                resolve({
                    ready: true,
                    wait: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                    })
                });
            } else {
                resolve({
                    ready: false,
                    wait: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        setTimeout(() => { resolve([1, 2, 3]); }, 1000);
                    })
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};

twoStagePromise(false).then((data) => {
    if (!data.ready) {
        console.log('loading...');
    }
    return data.wait;
}).then((result) => {
    console.log("recieved result", result);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("try-catch failed or inner promise failed")
});
```

After reading some of the comments I simplified the code a lot:

```
let twoStagePromise = (state: boolean): Promise<number[] | Promise<number[]>> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (state) {
                resolve([1, 2, 3]);
            } else {
                resolve(new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => { resolve([1,2,3])  }, 1000)))
            }
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};

twoStagePromise(false).then((dataOrPromise) => {
    if (dataOrPromise instanceof Promise) {
        console.log('loading...');
    }
    return dataOrPromise // continue the promise chain by returning the promise or data
}).then((result) => {
    console.log("recieved result", result);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("try-catch failed or inner promise failed", error)
});
```

Comment: ① Is this a code review question?  If so it might not be appropriate for Stack Overflow.  ② By what standard would you judge if an implementation is "better"? Could you clarify so that the question isn't subjective or soliciting opinions?

Comment: For one, you don't need `new Promise()` to just immediately return a resolved or rejected promise.  You can use `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()` to create those without using `new Promise()` with a callback.

Comment: Then, the whole notion of what you're doing with two stage promise just seems odd and likely unnecessary.  You can just return a single promise that resolves to your value, either immediately or later.    The caller then has simpler code.  It just `awaits` that promise and gets the value from the `await`, whether the value is immediately available or takes some time.

Comment: The "loading..." UI could be shown on a timer if the promise doesn't resolve within 100ms or something like that.

Comment: When you say the resource is available immediately, do you mean that it is available synchronously? If so, you could represent this as a synchronous nullable getter and an asynchronous getter that returns a possibly-already-resolved promise. No two stages required.

Comment: As jfriend00 says, you're just doing what promises already do. A promise that has already been fulfilled can have new `.then` handlers added to it, and it just yields up the same value forever. Promises already have the property "If a resource is available immediately then return it".

Comment: Look at the design of `fetch()` for a similar two-stage promise. Really your function should return a promise that either resolves with `{ready: true, value: [1,2,3]}` or with `{ready: false, wait() {…}}` where `wait()` returns a promise for the final value.

Answer (score 1):

You may make a function that explicitly may return both value or it's promise. In any case you can easily `await` it. To check if the result is syncronous, use `result instanceof Promise`

```
type Awaitable<T> = T | Promise<T>
function maybeImmediate<T>(
    call: () => Awaitable<T>,
    tryImmediate: boolean,
): Awaitable<T> {
    if (tryImmediate) {
        try {
            return call(); // you don't know if it's T or Promise<T> actually
        } catch (err) {
            // choose the one you want
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(err)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // make sure it's a promise
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => call())
    }
};

let cache: Record<string, string> = {};
function getCached(url: string): Awaitable<string> {
    if (cache[url]) return cache[url];
    return new Promise<string>(r => {
        setTimeout(() => r('result of ' + url), 1000)
    }).then(v => { cache[url] = v; return v })
}
```